# adding user to a Database using mongo c# driver

Tags: mongodb

I want to add a user to a newly created database in mongodb. I am using db.addUser(username,password).
But it is giving mongoAuthentication Exception. Please tell me the reason. I want to add a user so that next time when I use the same database, I can use it with the same set of crednetials as I passed to create a user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process for creating an admin user and regular users is documented here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-ConfiguringAuthenticationandSecurity

Comment: This does not answer the question. My requirement is precisely about adding an user to a mongo db, using Mongo C# Driver, and the chosen answer has nothing to do with Mongo C# Driver, at all.

Answer (score 4):

1. Start `mongod.exe` with `--auth` parameter. This will start your MongoDB with authentication mode enabled.
2. Since there will be no users when you start MongoDB for the first time, it will be considered as "localhost exception" (You should see a message saying "no users configured in admin.system.users, allowing localhost access" in the console). This means that, it is allowing you to create the first user in admin database (admin user), who will then have the authority to create other regular users.
3. To create admin user start `mongo.exe` and type following commands:

   ```
   > use admin
   > var user = {
       "user" : "adminUser",
       "pwd" : "adminPass",
       "roles" : [
           {
               "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
               "db" : "admin"
           }
       ]
   }

   > db.createUser(user);
   ```

   You can also accomplish this using C# code as follows:

   ```
   private static bool fnCreateAdminUser()
   {
       try
       {
           var user = new BsonDocument { { "createUser", "adminUser" }, { "pwd", "adminPass" }, { "roles", new BsonArray { new BsonDocument { { "role", "userAdminAnyDatabase" }, { "db", "admin" } } } } };
           new MongoClient().GetDatabase("admin").RunCommand<BsonDocument>(user);
           return true;
       }
       catch (MongoCommandException) { return true; }
       catch { return false; }
   }
   ```
4. Now your admin user is created and you can create other regular users for your database using this admin user. You can either use C# code or command line etc. depending on your implementation. Following is the sample C# method which creates a user for the specified database:

   ```
   private static bool CreateUser(string strDBName)
   {
       try
       {
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strDBName))
           {
               // prepare admin credentials
               MongoCredential cred = MongoCredential.CreateCredential("admin", "adminUser", "adminPass");
               MongoClientSettings setting = new MongoClientSettings();
               setting.Credentials = new[] { cred };

               var user = new BsonDocument { { "createUser", "regularUser" }, { "pwd", "regularPass" }, { "roles", new BsonArray { new BsonDocument { { "role", "readWrite" }, { "db", strDBName } } } } };
               new MongoClient(setting).GetDatabase(strDBName).RunCommand<BsonDocument>(user);
               return true;
           }
           else
           {
               return false;
           }
       }
       catch (MongoCommandException) { return true; } // if user already exists
       catch { return false; }
   }
   ```

You can also refer [this](http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.in/2015/02/introduction-to-mongodb-security.html) blog post for more details on this. It explains other things too, like adding/changing user roles etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you already created a db with a user in the admin database then you will need to connect with those credentials before you can create a new user.

Comment: It means I have to connect with admin's credentials. Then I can add user to a database or users for all database are stored in the admin's database

Comment: And if the db does not have any credentials

Answer (score 0):

You can add user using following code .

```
db.addUser(
    {
      user: "user",
      pwd: "pass",
      roles: [ "root" ]
    }
)
```